# How to use ESAPI to resolve JavaScript DOM XSS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, xss, esapi

We are using HP fortify Audit Workbench 3.80 to assess vulnerabilities in our applications.  Fortify marks the the following ExtJs JavaScript code as a Critical (the "worst") DOM XSS vulnerability:

```
function doAjaxCall(param1, param2, div) {
    var options = {
            url : url,
            params : {
                param1 : param1,
                param2 : param2
            },
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response, options) {
                processResponse(response, div);
            },
            failure: function(response, options) {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
    };
    Ext.Ajax.request(options);
}


function processResponse(response, div) {
     // SECURITY ISSUE HERE
     document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = '<br>' +
            'An error occurred with status code ' 
             + response.status + 
             '<br><br>';  
}
```

`response` is the response returned from an AJAX request.

Fortify says :

> method "processResponse" sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 100, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

I understand the issue and why it is an issue.  What I do not know is how to sanitize the input with [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API).  We are using ESAPI successfully for issues in our Java code, but I am not sure to resolve this specific issue in JavaScript.

I did find this JavaScript ESAPI library, [ESAPI4JS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_JavaScript_Readme), but I work in an extremely high security environment, and I do not have access to this library whatsoever.

How can I use ESAPI to sanitize the response?

**EDIT**

Added full ajax request code per user request.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker processResponse exists on the client side.  It is javascript function containing the line of code I included in the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It is just a wrapper function for the AJAX success callback.

Comment: You may want to include that in the code itself to give a clearer picture of what we're seeing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It truly is just a wrapper.  I have added the code anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Vulnerable:

```
document.write("Site is at: " + document.location + ".");
```

Not vulnerable:
    
    
    
        
    
    
    
    
    
    
    org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize();
    document.write($ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML("Site is at:    "+document.location));

You will need to initialize it before use. There is documentation on owasp's site.

@GeorgeStocker is wrong. A dom based xss typically is most dangerous because it cannot be handled server side. A perfect example would be the above which could easily be exploited by using a # before some code.

Also most client side xss filters can be bypassed by using onerror.

ey3

Comment: I think that code is from ESAPI4JS, is it not? I do not have access to that library.

Comment: I didn't read that it was 'document.location'; that makes sense.

Comment: @JOsh If that Library has the right license (like MIT), you could potentially include the source in your app inline.